# JS Web worker share the same scripts in multiple workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have multiple inline workers that I need to run. My problem is that every instance needs to share the same scripts that are imported. But on every instance that I created, it redownloads the scripts.

```
function workerFn(){
  importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js');
  // Each time this function will do something else
  postMessage(_.head([1,2,3]));
}

var code = workerFn.toString();
code = code.substring(code.indexOf("{") + 1, code.lastIndexOf("}"));

var blob = new Blob([code], {type: "application/javascript"});

var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
var worker2 = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

worker.onmessage = function (m) {};
worker2.onmessage = function (m) {};
```

So, in the above example, `lodash` will download twice. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you investigated using shared web workers?

Comment: @user9315861 Can you run multiple instances of a shared web worker at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Unfortunately, you cannot. It's up to the browser whether it downloads the scripts or not. I assume this does not even happen in every browser.

#### Another short answer:

The only way to avoid browser re-downloading the script would be to either a) have it compiled in your code (eg. web pack) or b) download it via AJAX, assuming CDN allows requests from other domains.

Neither of these thing is something I would recommend for production code.

Comment: Compiling the script doesn't change the fact that the code still is downloaded once per worker.

Comment: @torazaburo Browser caches the script after it downloads it once. So if you bundle all your libs under one file, you can always include just that file and then run whatever operation is needed.